# Get particular attribute value from django queryset (password authentication)

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to implement a login system into my web page and i want to check if the password entered inside the form is equal to the users password inside the database. I can get the password from the database inside a dictionary which is inside a queryset. How can i just get the value from this dictionary?

I want password_from_DB to equal to "password1234"

views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            password_entered = form.cleaned_data.get("password")

            find_person_by_email = Person.objects.filter(email=email)
            password_from_DB = find_person_by_email.values("password")
            print(password_from_DB)

            if password_from_DB  != password_entered :
                print("INCORRECT")
            else:
                print("CORRECT")

    context = {"title": "Login"}
    return render(request, "myApp/login.html", context)
```

The output from print(password_from_DB):

```
<QuerySet [{'password': 'password1234'}]>
```

Comment: by default all passwords are `hash'ed` with sha256 method in django, you can't retrieve `password` in its raw state, unless you saved it with your own way

Comment: these passwords have not been hash'ed. Just in raw state

Comment: `find_person_by_email = Person.objects.get(email=email)` >>`password_from_DB = find_person_by_email.password` >> `print(password_from_DB)`

Comment: You should never save passwords unhased!

Answer (score 0):

```py
def login(request):
    context = {"title": "Login"}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            password_entered = form.cleaned_data.get("password")

            find_persons_by_email = Person.objects.filter(email=email)
            if len(find_persons_by_email) != 0:
                print("User found by email is not unique")
                return render(request, "myApp/login.html", context)

            find_person_by_email = find_persons_by_email.first()
            password_from_DB = find_person_by_email.password

            if password_from_DB != password_entered :
                print("INCORRECT")
            else:
                print("CORRECT")

    return render(request, "myApp/login.html", context)
```

As an alternative to

```py
            find_persons_by_email = Person.objects.filter(email=email)
            if len(find_persons_by_email) != 0:
                print("User found by email is not unique")
                return render(request, "myApp/login.html", context)

            find_person_by_email = find_persons_by_email.first()
```

You could just write, but this will raise an `Exception` if the entered email is not unique mapped to a single user.

```py
            find_person_by_email = Person.objects.get(email=email)
```